# How does one share the value between a local a @State variable and a @Binding one in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

enum ValueType {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @State var value: ValueType?

    var body: some View {
        ChildView(boundValue: $value)
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var boundValue: ValueType?

    @State private var userInput: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter some text", text: $userInput)
    }
}
```

Here `ChildView` has a bound version of its parent's `@State ... answer` var. However the specific use case here involves a binding of an enum that can either have a `String` or `Int` value, whereas the `ChildView` has a `TextField` which involved a pure `String` value. How can the `ChildView`'s `userInput` value be transferred into its `boundValue.string(...)`?

Thank you for reading. Apologies if this question is a duplicate, I did search but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextField initializer also has two optional arguments for callbacks, `onEditingChanged` and `onCommit`, so another approach could be to put your update logic in there.

```
TextField("Enter some text", text: $userInput, onCommit: {
    self.boundValue = .string(self.userInput)
})
```

Comment: Perfect solution. If you want to use a button by pressing you to want to process the text data you can also follow the same solution, just use the onCommit closure part to a button's action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second Binding to bridge the string to your custom enum, as long as you handle all of the cases.  Here is an example:

```
import SwiftUI

enum ValueType {
  case string(String)
  case int(Int)
}

struct ParentView: View {
  @State var value: ValueType?
  var body: some View {
    ChildView(boundValue: $value)
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  let boundValue: Binding<ValueType?>
  let myCustomBinding: Binding<String>
  init(boundValue: Binding<ValueType?>) {
      myCustomBinding = Binding<String>.init(
      get: {
        switch boundValue.wrappedValue {
        case .string(let string):
          return string
        case .int(let int):
          return String(describing: int)
        case .none:
          return ""
        }
      },
      set: { (string: String) -> Void in
        boundValue.wrappedValue = Int(string).map{ ValueType.int($0)} ?? ValueType.string(string)
      })
    self.boundValue = boundValue.projectedValue
  }

  var body: some View {
    TextField("Enter some text", text: myCustomBinding)
  }
}
```